# com.bird.apple files, How to open it?

Tags: macos, icloud, backup, restore

I saw this post: [What is com.apple.bird? Why does it grow so big?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220007/what-is-com-apple-bird-why-does-it-grow-so-big/246539#246539?newreg=666fe3eca1bb4b00a54c750710550d1a) where they inform that the files in the directory com.apple.bird (session) is related to iCloud backup.
I have some huge files (140Gb total) and I wanna check what is inside before I decide to delete them or to save them. 
Is there any software or script that can open those files and show me all the contents?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Did you try the command that was specified in the answer you linked?  What did it generate?  What about the Python script that was referenced in another answer?  Finally, the highest voted and accepted answer makes a statement about deleting....

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Finder
2. Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while you click on the Go menu
3. Select Library
4. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now
5. Within the Library folder open the Caches folder
6. Now you'll see a com.apple.bird folder

You can browse within this folder to determine what's taking up space.

You may also want to read
[my answer to this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281266/whatsapp-using-huge-space-on-my-mac-ssd)